# Entity Framework 4.3 Multi-project installation

Tags: entity-framework, installation

I'm confused with regards to my code using latest Entety Framework.
I have 2 projects in the solution. I've used t4 templates to generate Self-Tracking Entities.
In project #1 I have just .edmx files and Entety Framework 4.3 installed thru NuGet PM. Now my second project has template-generated Context classes. So how do I make sure my second project also uses EF 4.3? Do I need to install it separatly for every project in my solution or can I just reference EntityFramework.dll? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Entity Framework package installation is project specific. I'd install it separately, so NuGet can manage the references.

To manage the package installation for multiple projects, open NuGet PM for Solution with 
"Tools->Library Package Manager->Nuget Package Manager for Solution..."
Go to the Installed tab (or Online), select EntityFramework and click Manage. Check/Uncheck the projects where to install EntityFramework.

Or, in the console pass the -ProjectName property to the install-package command.